# Why does the JavaScript .sort() method skip a Unicode card character hex letter for the suit, but not the following hex number for the card rank?

Tags: javascript, sorting, unicode

When I use the JavaScript `.sort()` method on an array of strings of HTML `<span>`'s that will display Unicode playing cards, the `.sort()` method will first sort the cards by the alphabetical order of the name of the suit as written in the `class` attribute of the `<span>` containing each playing card, but then the `.sort()` method will ignore the later Unicode hex number letter (a = spades, b = hearts, c = diamonds, and d = clubs) for the suit of the card, and yet `.sort()` will respect the final hex number for the rank of the card (1 = Ace on through E = King, skipping C = a royal Count card not used in poker).

For example, the following span would be used to display the Ace of Spades:

`<span onclick='cutCards(this.outerHTML);' class='spades'>&#x1f0a1;</span>`

The alphabetical order of the names of the suits in each class name attribute comes before the Unicode hex number in the span for each card, so I understand why the `.sort()` method would ignore the later Unicode hex letter order for each suit, but why should the `.sort()` method respect the rightmost Unicode hex number for the rank of the card?

I can probably work with it and ignore the question, but I would like to work on it with an understanding of what is happening.

I am trying to finish a program that will display the order of a deck of cards that, no matter where the deck is cut (but not shuffled), will always result in a win for the first player to be dealt cards in the game of Texas Hold'em.  The one deck that I am now working with is one of over a hundred thousand such decks that were found by the mathematician Jeremy Kun. See, https://jeremykun.com/2012/04/09/optimal-stacking-hold-em/

At present, the program allows any card to be clicked and have it become the top card of the cut, and then the program displays how the game would be played out. From there, I want to find (sort out) the best possible combination of cards for each player, describe the poker ranking of each hand, display those hands, and announce the winner.

Current Program Image After A Cut Card Is Chosen

[image]

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort): _"Note: In UTF-16, Unicode characters above \uFFFF are encoded as two surrogate code units, of the range \uD800-\uDFFF. The value of each code unit is taken separately into account for the comparison. Thus the character formed by the surrogate pair \uD655\uDE55 will be sorted before the character \uFF3A. "_

Comment: @Andreas It's customary in some languages to format headlines so that every word (but articles) is capitalised. But doesn't matter, Remy already edited it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the surrogate pairs, and the surrogate pairs for the Unicode playing cards have a very regular order. For example, the ace of hearts code `<span>&#xf10A1;</span>` will be seen by JavaScript as the surrogate pair \uDB84\uDCA1.

Notice that the ending A1 is at the end of both versions of the code:  A1 is at the end of the single hex value, and A1 is at the end of the second code of the surrogate pairs. I imagine that they call the first surrogate code the ‘high’ one because it comes first, even though it has a lower hex number when taken by itself. The high code of the surrogate pair for any Unicode playing card is always DB84, so it will always sort to the same place value. The ‘low’ code of the surrogate pair will always start with DC _ _ and then will add a hex letter of a, b, c, or d for the suit of the card, and then will end with the hex value for the rank of the card, 1 = Ace through E = King (C has to be skipped because it is a royal Count card not common to poker).

This can be verified with an online surrogate pair calculator by entering the long hex number and getting the surrogate pairs. See, http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm

Effectively, my original question was ‘Why does the JavaScript .sort() method alphabetically sort my card spans by the suit name in the class name attribute of my card spans, but then ignores the later suit hex digit in the code point, but then sorts by rank according to the final hex digit in the code point.?’

In trying to understand the answer by Andreas, I figured out that the .sort() method is not ignoring anything. When the suit name in the class name attribute orders all cards of the same suit together, the subsequent hex number for suit will be the same for every card of the same suit previously set, so the only thing left to sort after that will be the rank of each card of the same suit.

No problem, and thank you for the answer.